# Click Event of View Inside Framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Following layout Scenario

[image]

Want to implement the Click even of `TextView` ..but the `TextView` Click not working

Here is code Sample

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
        android:clickable="false">

        <customview
            android:id="@+id/custom"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp" 
            android:clickable="false"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/abc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/zero_done"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



        </LinearLayout>
```

My  `TextView` ClickEvent not working ...please  help me

Class Code

```
TextView view= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please show us the code where you assign the onClickListener?

Comment: Can you try to change it's id to something else, maybe you have another view with that id. Use something like tvBtn123

Comment: Use the android Hierarchy Viewer to check if the textView isn't behind some other view. https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Comment: post your customview code, coz everything else looks fine.

Comment: Can you just use 'implements OnClickListener' for the class, and in onCreate add 'view.setOnClickListener(this)' and then in the onClick method add if (v == view) {  // your toast here }

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call show method of Toast,so you have no idea whether TextView click event did happen or not.

Try this:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // don't miss show method.
```